# MongoDB SocketException Error : Connection refused

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb along with ExpressJS to run a RESTful API.
Sometimes while performing a long insert operation in a loop (where I do not close the Db connection) MongoDb server stops abruptly. When I try to connect Db via mongo shell I get the following error message.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: cause by :: Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2.6
exception: connect failed
exciting with code 1
```

The only fix I managed to find was restarting the whole server where mongoDb is installed.

Kindly help he fix this issue in a more formal manner, at least so that ExpressJS handles such kind of mongoDb downtime. The error message, although a bit explanatory, hasn't been useful to me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this usually happens if the MongoDB service is dead or inactive. Did you check the service status? Try

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```